# Different Level Navigation CSS

Tags: css, magento

I have a left hand navigation that I am trying to code with CSS.

At the moment the sub-categories (level 1) are showing as the 'active' color when the main one is selected (from level 0). When you click on a sub-category (level 1) it is then following the same css rules as the main category (level 0) but not until clicked.

What I want, is the subcategories (level 1) to show with a white background when the main category is selected (level 0) (opening the subcategories). Then, when an item is chosen within the subcategory (level 1) it follows a different rules (font to be in a different color for example).

Sorry, it's a little confusing to try to explain! Here is my CSS.. any help would be greatly appreciated! I just can't get my head around this one. The site is created using Magento, so I can't alter the html easily.

```
.vertnav-container {
margin-top:10px;
}

#vertnav li .vertnav-cat {
display:block;
width:210px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 12px;
}

#vertnav li a {
}

#vertnav .inactive .vertnav-cat {
background-image: url(../images/inactive_bgd.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#vertnav .next .vertnav-cat {
background-color:#b7de70;
}

#vertnav .prev .vertnav-cat {
background-color:#b7de70;
}

#vertnav li.parent .vertnav-cat {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight:bold;
}

#vertnav li.active .vertnav-cat {
background-color:#f59942;
background-image: url(../images/active_bgd.jpg);
font-weight:bold;
}

#vertnav li.inactive .vertnav-cat {
font-weight:normal;
}

#vertnav .level0 .vertnav-cat {
}

#vertnav .level1 .vertnav-cat {
padding-left:20px;
width:183px;
height: 5px;
border-bottom:1px dotted gray;
 }

#vertnav .level2 .vertnav-cat {
padding-left:20px;
width:172px;
}

#vertnav .level3 .vertnav-cat {
padding-left:30px;
width:162px;
}
```

UPDATE:
I think this is the html, but am not sure how I edit it as it's through Magento, will need to look this end if you think that's what needs to be done...

```
<div class="col-left sidebar"><div class="vertnav-container">
<div class="">
    <h4 class="no-display">Category Navigation:</h4>
    <ul id="vertnav">
<li class="first prev level0-inactive has-children level0 inactive fruit">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://****/fruit.html"><span>Fruit</span>      </a></span>

  </li>
  <li class="level0-active level0 active vegetables">
  <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://****/vegetables.html">    <span>Vegetables</span></a></span>

  </li>
  <li class="next level0-inactive level0 inactive meat">
   <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://****/meat.html"><span>Meat</span>    </a></span>

   </li>
   <li class="level0-inactive level0 inactive dairy">
   <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://****/dairy.html"><span>Dairy</span></a></span>

   </li>
   <li class="last level0-inactive level0 inactive for-the-pantry">
    <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http:****/pantry.html"><span>For the Pantry</span></a></span>

   </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML too?

Comment: Most certainly want to utilize some form of psuedo selectors. HTML please? I'll bust out a fiddle for ya.

Comment: @user3217495 my answer doesn't help you??

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't responded. Here is the most simplistic method I could come up to easily target different elements. The best I could do without seeing your HTML, but it should provide some guidance into how to structure your layout.

Few things. I'd use lists instead of a ton of classes, as your CSS would indicate you're doing.

Also, using `a:focus` **psuedo class** is an easy way to target the actively clicked link without using a bunch of additional classes and whatnot.

#### JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/v4n7G/3/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="leftNav">
    <li><a href="#">Head One</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Head Two</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    color:#AAA;
}
ul#leftNav {
    width:200px;
}
ul#leftNav li {
    list-style:none;
    color:#666;
}
ul#leftNav a:focus {
    color:green;
}
ul#leftNav ul a{
    color:red;
}
ul#leftNav ul a:focus {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The html is through Magento (which was an extension package) so I don't believe I can access the html. I only have access to the css.

Comment: If your Magneto file is producing HTML like that I would ditch it as soon as possible. I hope this is at least an acceptable answer. If so, please mark it as such. If not, I don't believe I can help further. CMS systems are horrible to work with IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believe I have found the HTML and updated my question above.

Comment: That's a lot of weirdo classes. Heading off for the nite. Good luck with you site. I hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="nav" class="sixteen columns">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="asia.html">Asia</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="europe.html">Europe</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    width:800px;
    margin:30px 50px;
   padding: 0;
    float:left;
}
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding:0 10px;
   background-color:#367FB3;
    color:white;
}


#nav li a:hover {
   background-color:#52baff;
    color:#fff;
}
//daf adf
/*--temp--*/
 #nav ul ul li {
    clear:left;
}
#nav ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:14em;
    top:0;
}
#nav ul ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    color: #242424;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
/*--end temp--*/
 #nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    color: #242424;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#367FB3;
}
#nav a:active {
    color:#367FB3;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 14em;
    /* Width to help Opera out */
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index:666;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px -10px;
    padding:0px;
}
#nav li:hover ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#nav li ul li:hover ul {
    display:block
}
#nav li:hover li, #nav li.hover li {
    float: none;
    line-height:30px;
}
#nav li:hover li a, #nav li.hover li a {
    background-color:#367FB3;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
#nav li li a:hover {
    background-color:#52baff;
    color:#fff;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vD3/11/)

Comment: @your_comment: He is unable to modify the HTML in the Magneto site. Probably a lost cause to force all this to work without a lot of backpedaling.